# MFMailComposeViewController sending status

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is there any way to get status from MFMailComposeViewController?
lets say I'm sending a email with 20 images, i want to show some loading and then after hide loading when sending is done.

Answer (score 1):

No. Once the user chooses to send an email and the delegate method is called in your app, the email is sitting in the outbox waiting to be sent by some background mail daemon. There is no API to get the status of such an email. Even if the mail can't be sent for some reason, there is no way for the app to get this information.

Answer (score -1):

```
try the delegate methods may be it help you.


#pragma mark - MailComposeController

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the question is about getting the status of the email after receiving the `MFMailComposeResultSent` result.